# New Companies API: cannot retrieve all the updates

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am not able to retrieve all the updates from a company page. I can only retrieve the last, happened 4 days ago, but not the previous, happened 1 month and more ago.

Has this anything to do with the new API that took effect on 12th of May?

This is the endpoint I use:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/1234567/updates?count=100&format=json&oauth2_access_token=xxx`

As already stated, I don't get the posts older than 1 month but I can get all the posts that are 4 days or younger.

Also on their test company profile, I can only retrieve posts that are 4 days or less.

EDIT:
Scratch the last: On the test company profile I can retrieve up to the 25th of April 2015.

EDIT2: On the page I am trying to grab, there are dozens of updates, but I seem to get only the last 2 (the previous are more than a month old) - sorry for being repetitive, just trying to give as much context as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is seems like API limitation:

From https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages

Only the most recent 50 updates for events of type status-update will be returned.  For all other event types, the request will return all the updates within the past 20 days, or 250 total updates - whichever comes first.

Comment: I agree.. but it is weird because I can get a full month of history from their company mock profile...

Comment: I guess that's the only explanation to that- although the feed from that endpoint varies if I add an activity.. Well thanks!